# JQuery: Create a main video and list of two or more video thumbnails beneath it

Tags: jquery, video

I would like to create a video box at the top which plays a video and list of two or three video links (thumbnails) below it that when clicked they will be played on the top video box in JQuery.

Thanks.

P.S. I will manually create the thumbnails. Also, the video embed codes/urls are from livestream.com

Answer (score 0):

Here are some players to consider (note that they will mostly do what you want out-of-the-box):

- FlowPlayer : http://flowplayer.org/ (free version has FlowPlayer logo)
- JWPalyer   : http://www.longtailvideo.com/players (free version has JWPlayer logo)
- jPlayer    : http://jplayer.org/ (free/open-source)

These are in no particular order and these are not the only players around but they all have fairly active communities. When looking through the documentation for the different players make sure to check-out the "JavaScript API" sections that show you how to load/play/pause/seek/etc. videos using JavaScript.

One major strength of these players is that they allow you to use `<embed>` tags for older browsers and `<video>` tags for newer browsers.